# Itemconfigure() and memory leak with tkinter

Tags: python, memory, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

My code (see below) is supposed to display a start/stop button, a scale button to select the speed of the visualization and a canvas with many rectangles that randomly change color with time.

When I run this piece of code, the memory usage increases dramatically with time (if you run, you need to increase the speed to about 10 to see it more easily). At work (on a Windows 7 workstation) where I tested it at first it becomes essentially unusable (it become very very slow) after few minutes while on my Mac laptop it survives a bit longer although the memory usage increases steadily.

After having looked for the culprit, I have come across multiple threads including [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/tktoolkit/bugs/2859/) from Tk Toolkit that dates back to 2010 where they mention that there is a problem with `itemconfigure()` when it is used to change color, which is exactly what I am doing.

Commenting the `"self.update_canvas()"` function in the `self.run_InfiniteT_MC()` function solves the problem as far as I can see and seems to agree with the diagnostic that `itemconfigure()` to change color may still be problematic.

Note that I have also tried to delete the changing rectangles via the command "self.canvas.delete(self.rect[i])" and then re-creating them but that does not change my memory problem at all.

I have also tried to destroy the whole canvas via `"self.canvas.destroy()"` and recreating everything from scratch each time in need to update the image but again that fails to solve my memory problem.

**Is there anything that I can do to solve this memory problem without changing my whole code (here this just a small piece of it)?**

EDIT: After indenting properly the command `self.after` , the problem disappeared; so the `itemconfigure()` command is not to blame at all, at least not for this problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from numpy import *
from random import randint

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.columnconfigure(0, pad = 10)
        self.grid()
        self.count = 0
        self.create_widgets()


def create_widgets(self):
        "create an array of cells all initiated with the same value"
        self.nx = 70
        self.ny = self.nx
        self.ntot = self.nx*self.ny
        self.state = [0 for x in range(self.ntot)]
        for x in range(self.ntot):
            self.state[x] = 0 #0 is down, 1 is right, 2 is up, 3 is left ...modulo 4
        "create a scale button to choose speed of dynamics"
        self.ScaleSpeedVar = IntVar
        self.ScaleSpeed = Scale(self, from_=1, to =20, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "SimuSpeed", variable = self.ScaleSpeedVar, font =('Helvetica','18'))
        self.ScaleSpeed.grid()
        self.ScaleSpeed.set(1)

"create a button that starts/stops the dynamics"
        self.do_run = False
        self.startclick = True
        self.buttonStartStop = Button(self, text = "Start/Stop", font =('Helvetica','18'))
        self.buttonStartStop["command"] = self.start_stop_simu
        self.buttonStartStop.grid()
"create a big canva to contain the simulation cells"
        self.size = 500
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.size, height=self.size, bg ="red")
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.width = 1
        self.rect = [0 for x in range(self.ntot)]
        for i in range(self.ntot):
            self.rectsize = self.size/self.nx
            self.rect[i] = self.canvas.create_rectangle((i%(self.nx))*self.rectsize, self.rectsize*(i//self.nx), (i%(self.nx))*self.rectsize+self.rectsize, self.rectsize*(i//self.nx)+self.rectsize, fill="red", tag = i, width = self.width)

def start_stop_simu(self):
    if self.startclick:
        self.start_simu()
        self.startclick = False
    else :
        self.stop_simu()
        self.startclick = True

def start_simu(self):
    self.do_run = True
    self.run_InfiniteT_MC()

def stop_simu(self):
    self.do_run = False

def run_InfiniteT_MC(self):
    if self.do_run:
        self.simuspeed = pow(2,self.ScaleSpeed.get())
        for i in range(self.simuspeed):
            self.cellID = randint(0,self.ntot-1)
            self.angle = 2*randint(0,1)-1
            self.state[self.cellID] = (self.state[self.cellID]+self.angle)%4
        self.update_canvas()
    self.after(1, self.run_InfiniteT_MC)

def update_canvas(self):
    for i in range(self.ntot):
        if self.state[i] == 0:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect[i], fill = "red")
        if self.state[i] == 2:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect[i], fill = "blue")
        if self.state[i] == 1:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect[i], fill = "green")
        if self.state[i] == 3:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect[i], fill = "yellow")
    self.canvas.update_idletasks()


root = Tk()
root.title("Problematic code")
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you change the colors to hex values (eg: `"#ff0000"` instead of `"red"`, does that have any effect?

Comment: that's a good point, I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the call to `self.after`. Every time you start the simulation a *new* infinite loop is created (which is never stopped). Indenting the line with `self.after`so that it is within the `if` statement should resolve your issue, since then such a loop will be terminated when `self.do_run` becomes `False`.

Comment: Yes, that's spot on; that was just bad programming.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is a memory leak in the tk core when allocating colors, then the only fix is to avoid doing the `itemconfigure` to change the color. One solution would be to create four rectangles for each position, one of each color. You can then modify the stacking order to have the color that you want on top, which will hide the other colors.

Clearly, this solution requires four times the number of canvas objects, but unless you're drawing hundreds of thousands, it shouldn't matter. The canvas can handle tens of thousands of objects fairly well.

Comment: yes I thought about this one and that would do the job for the visual purpose I am talking about here but the issue is that in the current project I have each rectangle is supposed to be clickable as well so that you can also change the color when you click on them. It works perfectly fine as it is if there was no memory leak...

Comment: Ok let's assume I want to give a go to your idea in the end. How do I actually manage to change the stacking order at the level of single squares? Can I do a `grid_forget()` at the level of a single square `self.rect[i]` in the above code?